# "Error loading dependencies": Creating a dash application to upload a csv and render graphs using any combination of columns

Tags: python, flask, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to render a graph using columns of an uploaded csv. The first callback is running but when I add the second callback the browser page says "Error loading dependencies". None of the consoles are generating any error. Can someone point out the flaw in my code or simply suggest a way to generate a graph using dropdown?

I have tried returning just the "options" to the dropdown, instead of the whole dropdown to the div. But it hasn't worked for me either. I have tried running on other browsers as well

```
import dash
import dash_table
import pandas as pd

import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

import numpy as np
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import base64
import io


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True


app.layout = html.Div([html.Div([
html.H5("Upload Files"),
dcc.Upload(id = 'upload-data',
           children = html.Div(['Drag and Drop or',
                                html.A('Select Files')]),
                                style={
                                    'width': '100%',
                                    'height': '60px',
                                    'lineHeight': '60px',
                                    'borderWidth': '1px',
                                    'borderStyle': 'dashed',
                                    'borderRadius': '5px',
                                    'textAlign': 'center',
                                    'margin': '10px'
                                },
                                multiple=False)
]),
html.Div(id = 'output-table'),
html.Div(id = 'x-value', style = {'width' : '48%' , 'display' : 'inline-block'}),

html.Div(id = 'y-value', style = {'width' : '48%' , 'display' : 'inline-block'}),


html.Div(dcc.Graph(id = "first_graph",
                    config={
        'displaylogo': False,
    }))
] , style = {"padding" : 10})

def parse_contents(contents, filename):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None

    return df

@app.callback([Output('output-table', 'children'),
               Output('x-value', 'children'),
               Output('y-value', 'children')],
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
               Input('upload-data', 'filename')])
def update_columns(contents, filename):
    if contents is not None:
        df = parse_contents(contents, filename)
        if df is not None:
            head = df.head()
            return  html.Div([
                    html.Div(id='datatable-output'),
                    dash_table.DataTable(
                    id='datatable',
                    columns =[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
                    data = head.to_dict("rows")
            )
        ]), [dcc.Dropdown(
                 id = 'xaxis',
                 options = [{'label':i , 'value':i} for i in df.columns],
                 #value ='my_x',
                 placeholder = 'Select X-axis value'
        )] , [dcc.Dropdown(
                 id = 'yaxis',
                 options = [{'label':i , 'value':i} for i in df.columns],
                 #value = 'my_y',
                 placeholder = 'Select Y-axis value'
        )]
        else:
            return 'Cannot load the file','',''
    else:
      return '', '', ''



@app.callback(Output('first_graph', 'figure'),
          [Input('xaxis' , 'value'),
          Input('yaxis' , 'value'),
          Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
           Input('upload-data', 'filename')])
def update_graph(my_x , my_y,contents,filename):
    if contents is not None:
        df = parse_contents(contents, filename)
        if df is not None:
            if (my_x is not None) and (my_y is not None):
                return  {'data': [go.Scatter( x = df[my_x],
                                             y = df[my_y],
                                             mode = " lines + markers",
                                             marker = dict(size = 15,
                                                           color = "rgb(54,321,123)",
                                                           symbol = "circle",
                                                           line = dict(width = 2)
                                                          )
                                             )],
                        'layout': go.Layout(title = 'Dashboard',
                                            xaxis = {'title' : my_x},
                                            yaxis = {'title' : my_y},
                                            hovermode = "closest"
                                            )
                                            }
            else:
                return {}
    else:
        return {}
```